# How to get instagram saved posts including collections tags?

Tags: collections, instagram, instagram-api, posts

When you save a post in instagram, you have the option to organize it by a custom tag that you type. Instagram calls it `Collections`.

So I'm trying to get access to my Instagram saved posts, which is neatly done by this tool https://github.com/pietrocaselani/Instagram-Saved-Posts, which at the same time is powered by the `instagram-private-api`, https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api.

All in all that's what I want, but my idea is to access `saved` posts, yes, but including the collection tag that you type when saving such posts. I already manually categorized them how I wanted, now i want to access to my categorized saved posts. Sadly that tool doesn't provide such field when generating the output .json, which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "webLink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/CC7ADvDjmwe",
    "code": "CC7ADvDjmwe",
    "caption": "Rotational Bistable Compliant Mechanisms\n\nThere are no words to describe the happiness that I feel! I've been working on this for months, trying different mathematical models, different geometries, different shapes\n\nIt might look simple, but it's extremely useful for me. I can interconnect this units in a Metamaterial, either as a switch or a \"Mechanical battery\" for soft-robotic applications\n\nI need to improve it, the more energy it can store, the better, so more spins would be great  if not I can connect them in serie. For more content: @davidzindustries \n\n.\n.\n.\n#3dprinting #3dprinter #mechanicalengineering #cad #innovate #robotics #3dprinters #filament #additivemanufacturing #keyshot #ingenieros #Prusa #3ddruck #impressao3d #arduinoproject #maker",
    "imagesLink": [
      "https://instagram.fpac1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/110051574_186432479566857_8003862276119818086_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fpac1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=peIAMu-DiWUAX9ruISK&oh=040ef5bb2e721abb1e2c789b2d03be4e&oe=5F42C4E6&ig_cache_key=MjM1ODQ3OTA4NjU0MjU0Nzk5OA%3D%3D.2"
    ]
  },

  {
    "webLink": "https://www.instagram.com/p/CC6gmZvKVeR",
    "code": "CC6gmZvKVeR",
    "caption": "Printed Ironman SD card holder by @virtikus_3dprint \n.\nRepost: @shareyour3dprints\n⚊⚊⚊\n Follow @makers_moment\n In collaboration with: @youbionic\n⚊⚊⚊\n#3dprinter #3dprinting #anycubicphoton #anycubic #resin #maker #make\n#filament #pla #prusa #additivemanufacturing #3ds #3dprinted #3dmodel #3dart #3d #3dprinters #3dparts #3ddesign #3dmodeling #3dprint #3dprinting #infinity #makersspace #shareyour3dprints #makersmovement #makersgonnamake",
    "imagesLink": [
      "https://instagram.fpac1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/109846063_307167223970226_778837425609213913_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fpac1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=AIQmW1rNne4AX-ldIri&oh=e05cce12edea90864b8f90b821ebcb24&oe=5F42E6E2&ig_cache_key=MjM1ODM0MDczMTM0NTEzMTQwOQ%3D%3D.2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried looking the output of the items in key `saved` inside the output `Feed` of `instagram-private-api`, but couldn't find anything related to the tags I wrote in my Collections in Instagram.

So anyone here knows something that could help me out? It would be greatly appreciated.